# Logging in Application Insights for .NET Core 2.1 Console app with LoggerFactory

Tags: .net, azure, console-application, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a .NET Core 2.1 Console application. I have added all the Nuget packages needed.

```
private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(services);
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
        .CreateLogger<Program>()
    var service = serviceProvider.GetService<TestClass>();
    service.TimmerTriggerTask();
}

private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .Build();
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry("8028437c-1111-2222-8293-2cf3f3f106a8"); //instrumentation key
    services.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole());
}

TestClass.cs
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<TestClass> _logger;

    public TestClass(ILogger<TestClass> logger)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ctor");
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void TimmerTriggerTask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timer");
    //LOG BELOW IN APPLICATION INSIGHTS
        _logger.LogTrace("Hello World");
        _logger.LogInformation(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

I need to log all the information and exceptions in Application Insights. looking to integrate loggerfactory with applicationInsights.

I am looking for something what we can do in .NET Core Web app

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseApplicationInsights()
loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, defaultLogLevel);
```

Please help me as how do i use logger classes to log into applicationinsights.

Please provide an alternative solution if what i am doing is incorrect.

Comment: For an alternative, you can directly use the Track_xxx functions in application insights.

Comment: Are you not getting logs logged via `Ilogger` in Application Insights? Looks like you did the right thing.

Comment: No. It doesn't appear in App Insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update:

For .net core 2.1 console app, you can use the following code:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey = "your instrumentation key" };

            ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddSingleton(x => telemetryClient);

            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
            loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(provider, LogLevel.Information);

            var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
            logger.LogInformation("a test from 0911 again...");
            logger.LogError("a error test from 0911 again...");


            Console.WriteLine("aaa");

            telemetryClient.Flush();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
```

After running, in the visual studio output window, I can see the telemetry data are sent, screenshot as below:
[image]

And also, it was also shown in azure portal, screenshot as below:
[image]

Comment: Isn't this code snippet for ASP.net core MVC project? i am looking for Asp.Net core console app.

Comment: @Sanketh, the code has been updated for .net core console app, please take a try.

Comment: How do i dependency inject ILogger in my TestClass so that when i implement logger.LogError it logs in app insights?

Comment: Hi @Sanketh, could you please post another question for this issue? If it's out of my scope, I can help you escalate the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

LoggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights has been deprecated. Add a reference to [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights/) and use the following code.  You can find a full example from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#console-application).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

        // Channel is explicitly configured to do flush on it later.
        var channel = new InMemoryChannel();
        services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>(
            (config) =>
            {
                config.TelemetryChannel = channel;
            }
        );

        services.AddLogging(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConsole();
            builder.AddApplicationInsights("[AI Instrumentation Key here]");
        });

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var logger = provider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();

        logger.LogInformation("This will show up in Application Insights"); 

        // Explicitly call Flush() followed by sleep is required in Console Apps.
        // This is to ensure that even if application terminates, telemetry is sent to the back-end.
        channel.Flush();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

You can add custom dimensions to implement structured logging by using [log message templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-message-template).

```
public void DoTheThings()
{ 
    var id = 12345;
    var duration = 300;

    logger.LogInformation(
        "Did the things for Id: {actionId} in {durationMs}ms. Params: {p2}, {p1}", 
        id, duration, "param1", "param2");
}
```

This will produce a trace in Application Insights with the message:

```
"Did the things for Id: 12345 in 300ms.  Params: param1, param2"
```

and customDimensions including:

```
{ 
    "actionId": "12345",
    "durationMS": "300",
    "p2" : "param1",
    "p1" : "param2"
}
```

Notice that:

1. The message template is **not** an interpolated string.
2. The property name in customDimensions is based on the message template
   not the argument.
3. The template properties are bound to arguments in sequence not by name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question some months ago and ended up building my own log provider that manages a TelemetryClient to send the log to AI.

Meanwhile I think that Microsoft has built a package exactly for that:

Check it out here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore.

Comment: Yes, time to back out all of those libraries we had to implement for ourselves in "the early days" :-).